# Specific users to download ios app, is it possible?

Tags: ios

One of my clients wants to restrict only specific users to download an iOS app, Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You cannot control this from App Store. 

But if you use testflight to share your app then you can control it to install on specific devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the iOS Developer Enterprise Program is what you seek. [enterprise License](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

You can't restrict who you sell to on the App Store.